# Why the connection to Gmail server is change my mails situation from "Unread" to "Read"?

Tags: android, gmail, jakarta-mail

I can receive my mails from Gmail Server and show theme on a listview on my Android Project. Yesterday, I started to change my mail's imageview for "unread" or "read" situation. But, then I realized that when my application connected to Gmail Server and receiving my mails, the RECENT mails become SEEN mails. And because of this reason I can't set my imageview's for unread mails.

I mean; I want to receive my mails from Gmail Server without changing their situations on Gmail Server. I want to receive them 3 unread and 4 read as in server.

What should I do for doing that?

My connection code sample is:

```
public Message[] ConnectionToServer(String email, String password)
            throws Exception 
        {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
        URLName server = new URLName("imaps://" + email + ":" + password + "@imap.gmail.com/INBOX");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        folder = session.getFolder(server);

        if (folder == null) 
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);     
        messages = folder.getMessages();

        for (int i = messages.length - 1; i >= 23; i--) 
        {
            Part p = messages[i]; 

            subject = messages[i].getSubject();

                     if (messages[i].isSet(Flags.Flag.RECENT)) {
            isSet = true;
            System.out.println("Recent");
            isSetlist.add(String.valueOf(isSet));
        }
        if (messages[i].isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) 
        {
            isSet = false;
            System.out.println("Read");
            isSetlist.add(String.valueOf(isSet));
        }
        else
        {
            isSet = true;
            System.out.println("Recent");
            isSetlist.add(String.valueOf(isSet));
        }

                        body = getText(p);

            list.add(body);
        }
        return (Message[]) messages;
    }
```

I am using getContent in getText() method

```
public String getText(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException {

        if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
            boolean textIsHtml = false;
            String s = (String) p.getContent();

            textIsHtml = p.isMimeType("text/html");
            return String.valueOf(s);
        }

        if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) {
            // prefer html text over plain text
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
            String text = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                    if (text == null)
                        text = getText(bp);
                    continue;
                } else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                    String s = getText(bp);
                    if (s != null)
                        return String.valueOf(s);
                } else {
                    return getText(bp);
                }
            }
            return text;
        } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                String s = getText(mp.getBodyPart(i));
                if (s != null)
                    return String.valueOf(s);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the message flags (to determine if the message is SEEN or not) before you access the content.  Accessing the content normally sets the SEEN flag.

Comment: How can I change this situation. I mean ; When the user open my application, his/her inbox mails will be set SEEN.. I dont want to change anything on server, I will change the server's mails situations when the user click the mail on my listview. Otherway server's mail mode shouldnt change

Comment: In your ConnectionToServer method above, you're accessing all the message content when you connect to the server.  It's not clear when you're checking for the SEEN flag, but if it's after calling this method, that's why it's not working for you.

Comment: Oh, and be sure to read this FAQ entry: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes

Comment: I changed my code and edit it into my question with flags, with that code in my application everything working perfect. But still in server is make recent mails to seen mails

Comment: I read the entry for 3 times but I dont get it what is the main purpose of this entry. I am sorry, but I really have to fix this issue, it is for my graduation project and I will give my project to school in one week, my project is destroyed because of this...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how else to explain it to you.  Maybe someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the folder in READONLY mode if you don't need to do any modifications - alternately, try preserving the `Message` [flags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/Flags.Flag.html#SEEN) across `getContent` calls.

Comment: You are right about Readonly mode. But in my application should do receive mails and send mails. I dont want to do any modifications on Server mails as you said. How can I do that with ReadWrite mode?  And also I am sorry but I didnt understand what did you mean on your alternately... sentence. Maybe you can address me some examples